# Rails Paperclip interpolates and before_save with custom id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my app (Rails 5.2), my model uses an id with UUID type .
I have created one more field: id_server which will be the id I want to use with paperclip for :id_partition to create multiple folders (default id_partition works with id field, not with another field).

I have done that:

```
before_save do
  id_server = Photo.maximum(:id_server) + 1
end
```

to create the next id_server.

And for Paperclip:

```
# paperclip
has_attached_file :file, path: "/upload/:class/:attachment/:id_server_partition/:style/:basename.:extension",
styles: { :tiny => "140x140>", :small => "160x240", :high => "640x960" }                   

validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png'] }
validates_attachment :file, size: { in: 0..5.megabytes }

# create multiple folders path with id_server
Paperclip.interpolates :id_server_partition do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.id_server_partition
end
def id_server_partition
  ("%09d".freeze % id_server).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/".freeze)
end
```

The fact is before_save() seems to never be called before Paperclip.interpolates.

id_server is nil in:

```
("%09d".freeze % id_server).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/".freeze)
```

> can't convert nil into Integer

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it was because self was missing in:

```
before_save do
end
```

so this works, and the id_server is created here:

```
self.id_server = Photo.maximum(:id_server) + 1
```

but not this:

```
id_server = Photo.maximum(:id_server) + 1
```

But here, no need of the self before id_server:

```
("%09d".freeze % id_server).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/".freeze)
```